# adding hobby to a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a rails application. I'm a ruby-on-rails newbie.
I have a User model and a Hobby model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hobbies
end

class Hobby < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

During the new user registration, I have used a text box where I enter a value for hobby. Then, when I press a button 'Add hobby', a method in UsersController **add_hobby** is to be called where I intend to append the value entered for hobby by user to the user i.e
`@user.hobbies << hobby`
However, my problem is that the user object has not been saved yet, so there is no way to access a particular user object. How do I get around this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build nested form as such in your templates:

```
<%= form_for @user do |user_form| %>
  <%= user_form.text_field :name %>
  <% for hobby in @user.hobbies %>
    <%= user_form.fields_for hobby, :index => hobby do |hobby_form|%>
      <%= hobby_form.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then add `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hobbies

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hobbies, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, Its better to save the hobbies after user has been created. Afterall its not logical to save user's hobbies even without having a user created.

If you are allowing multiple hobbies for a user, have a javascript array in client side. when user added a hobby add it to the javascript array and update the page. (You can do it with some DHTML / Javascript). When you are saving the user pass the hobby array and in the controller you can split and save the hobbies.

cheers

sameera

Comment: Ok, I created the user first. Then I redirected the user to complete his profile. The profile page looks like this <h1>User successfully created</h1>
<h3>Would you like to complete your profile now?</h3>

  <%= render @profile %>

  <%= render @address %>

  <%= button_to 'Save',{
              :controller => "users", 
              :action => "update", 
              :id => @user.id,
              :profile => @profile, 
              :address => @address
             }, :method => :put %>